# How to load custom fonts in a next.js app when it's in production?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Ok, so the question might sound extremely easy to be answered and trust me I've gone through the next js docs already! I think what I am experiencing in my next js project might be bug or something that I'm missing out.

I have custom fonts in .ttf format and they are inside a folder called ''fonts'' inside of the public folder, when I run my project with `npm run dev` and check it on localhost my fonts are imported and applied properly to the pages but in production my next js app just seems not to be able to load/find the fonts!

When I open my project in production the standard font is applied and in the console tab I can see an error message saying: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()` and that message is associated with the fonts that were not loaded/found!

So the main problem is that in development everything works and expected and the error/bug doesn't happen, only in production that the fonts dont get loaded or found.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in my previous project was

1. Put the fonts in `public/static` or somewhere
2. In the same directory  as the fonts put a `CSS` file where the fonts are declared

Example: `/public/fonts/fonts_style.css`

```
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Raleway';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url('../fonts/raleway-v19-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
      src: local(''),
           url('../fonts/raleway-v19-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
           url('../fonts/raleway-v19-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
           url('../fonts/raleway-v19-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
           url('../fonts/raleway-v19-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
           url('../fonts/raleway-v19-latin-regular.svg#Raleway') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

3. And import that in css in your `pages/_document.js` file.

Example:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Html>
            <Head>
                <link href="/fonts/fonts_style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            </Head>
        </Html>
    )
}
```